# Reading HTTP response from UART

Tags: python, parsing, serial-port, location-services

I'm using a Telit GE864-GPS modem, which runs a dialect of Python 1.5.2. The Python module has access to the modem using a buffered UART, which *may* still be receiving when reading starts. The following code makes sure the entire response is read, and return either the response body or '0' on timeout.

```
def receiveReponse ( ):

    # MOD.secCounter() provides the current time in seconds
    timeout = MOD.secCounter() + 10

    str = ""
    length = ""
    newlinepos = 0

    while ( MOD.secCounter() < timeout ):

        newlinepos = str.find("\n\r")

        if ( (newlinepos != -1) and not length ):

            newlinepos = newlinepos + 2
            pos = str.find("Content-Length:") + 15

            while ( str[pos] != '\n' ):
                length = "%s%s" % (length, str[pos])
                pos = pos + 1

            length = int(length) + newlinepos

        else:
            MOD.sleep(5)

            # MDM receive reads the current UART buffer
            str = str + MDM.receive(1)

        if ( length and len(str) >= length ):
            return str[newlinepos:(newlinepos+length)]

    return 0
```

The entire procedure seems rather overcomplicated. Am I missing some obvious simplifications?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
        while ( str[pos] != '\n' ):
            length = "%s%s" % (length, str[pos])
            pos = pos + 1
```

could be just

```
        length = string.split(str[pos:], '\n')[0]
```

Comment: Did string objects have a `split` method in 1.5.2? I think this wasn't added until 1.6. Before that you had to `import string` and then call `string.split`.

Comment: @GarethRees You are right; edited.